# How to make a table size on grid like a container size in ABAP

Tags: abap, alv

I need help with ABAP alv_grid.

First, I'll show you my code:

```
 "descibe data
  data: grid            type ref to cl_gui_alv_grid,
        container       type ref to cl_gui_custom_container,
 "create a container
    if container is initial.
        container = new cl_gui_custom_container(                    =
            container_name              = 'CONTAINER'
    *        lifetime                    = LIFETIME_DEFAULT

        ).
"create a grid
if grid is initial.
    grid = new cl_gui_alv_grid( i_parent = container ).


call method grid->set_table_for_first_display
      exporting
       is_layout            = wa_layout
       it_toolbar_excluding = gt_toolbar_excluding

      changing
        it_outtab            = lt_variable
        it_fieldcatalog      = it_fcat.
```

As a result I have something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPaIH.png) (red lines on a picture is what exactly I need to get in final).

My target is to make a table size like a container size and I don't know where I should add a parameter to reach this goal (if this is possible).

P.S. if it's necessary, the layout is:

```
  data wa_layout TYPE lvc_s_layo.
  wa_layout-cwidth_opt = 'X'.
```

Comment: Haven't you created a screen as well, which you call on the way (CALL SCREEN ...)? On this screen you created the custom container, (CONTAINER) right? You can modify the size of the container here (SE80 => Screens)

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai yeah i'd created the screen with a custom control before, but the idea was to make a table (that i tried to dispaly) size LIKE a custom control size if it's possible.
( i know that i can modify the size of the container, but the task is a little bit different). Anyway, thanks for advice)

Comment: looks like I misunderstood the question. I am not aware of such functionality. The cwidth_opt in the layout works the other way around, it makes the table as small as possible (for example if a column is 10 character by default, but all values in there are 5 chars only, than it will be also displayed with 5 chars (no white space)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for trying :)

Comment: There is no automatic way to do this. `cwidth_opt = 'X'` adjusts only **individual** columns **to their max text sizes**, not to the total length of container. To achieve your goal you should calculate the total, then divide the total length by column count and set their lengths one by one. In case  of manual setting remove `cwidth_opt` as it overrides manual setting.